# Allocating memory - kernel mode (OS X)

Tags: macos, kernel, allocation

Everytime I try to allocate space in kernel mode I get a kernel panic.
Given 'foo' - a function that takes place in kernel mode, I tried allocating space on the stack and using:

```
OSMalloc
```

Referenced here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Kernel/Reference/OSMalloc_header_reference/Reference/reference.html

But still no luck. Everytime I run this kernel code (kext) which uses 'foo' I get a kernel panic. 
How do I suppose to allocate space when in kernel mode then? What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm , I got it fixed using 'IOMalloc' @ IOKit.
It now allocates memory successfully and without panics ^^

thanks